# pointer to register address

Tags: c++, pointers

I usually have a decent understanding of pointers when it comes to referencing another variable in a program but what about referencing/writing to registers.
Are these two code versions going to perform the same?

```
#define REGISTER 0x0001 
volatile unsigned int* baseAddress = (unsigned int*) 0x60000000;
baseAddress[REGISTER] = 0x10101010;


volatile unsigned int* realRegister = (unsigned int*) 0x60000004;
realRegister = 0x10101010;
```

Comment: having a `#define REGISTER` has nothing to do with accessing hardware registers. `REGISTER` here is just used as an array index.

Comment: Do you mean CPU registers or memory mapped io ports? Some folks confuse the two.

Comment: Actually a DSP registers. I want to write to them to configure the different periperals on the chip. Examples of code are hard to come by.

Comment: Those DSP I/O registers are memory mapped so they have addresses. There are some older computers (like PDP 10) that memory mapped the main registers. I don't know if there are any current computers that have their main registers memory mapped.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a pointer or reference to a register. Registers do not form part of the computer’s main memory, and are not addressable using memory addresses.

Your code pieces, despite using a `#define` called `REGISTER`, are completely unrelated to registers. They attempt to write to normal, addressable memory. On *some* operating system architectures, specific memory addresses may be mapped directly to hardware ports (including, on some devices, registers). Most modern operating systems, however, don’t support this. They use the concept of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) instead, and pointers do not map directly to hardware locations.

Concerning the code you’ve posted, the two pieces are *not* identical. The second won’t compile because you are trying to assign an integer to a pointer. You can make it compile by dereferencing the pointer before the assignment (`*realRegister = 0x10101010;`) but the two pieces of code are *still* not identical:

The first piece of code writes its value at the address

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x60000000) + sizeof(unsigned int)
```

The second piece of code, by contrast, writes its value at the address

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x60000000) + 4
```

– The two pieces of code are only identical on machines where `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`.

Comment: FYI, some hardware devices have addressable units called *registers*, for example a UART.  Many devices have their registers specified in a sequential order.  So for example, the UART Receive Status register can be referred to by using an index from the base address of the UART.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Hence my caveat, “including, on some devices, registers”. To be fair, when I wrote the answer I was assuming that the OP was talking about a conventional operating system with virtual memory – now it sounds as if he might be talking about an embedded chip instead, so the first part of my answer might be a bit less applicable.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, the term **register** has two conceptual meanings:  a location inside the processor to hold values and a hardware addressable device's place to hold a value.

Let's skip the part about processor registers since those don't have addresses that the outside world can access. (Some processors do.)

Let's use for example a UART which is a device that converts parallel data to serial data, often used for output data from an embedded system.

Considering only the transmit section, there is a status register and a data register.  The status register has bits that say when it is finished transmitting the character.  The data register holds the character to be transmitted.

Let's assume these are 32-bit wide sequential registers and they start at the base address of 0x1000.

You can set up stencil as:

```
uint32_t * UART_BASE = (uint32-t *) 0x1000;
```

The status register can be referenced as `UART_BASE[0]` and the data register as `UART_BASE[1]`.

There are other ways to represent the hardware device, such as using a structure and each register as a field within the structure; or each register has a separate pointer.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `(*realRegister) = 0x10101010;`, but otherwise, yes, those appear to be the same.

Comment: -1 since this answer is inaccurate (assumption about the size of `unsigned int`) and doesn’t really tackle the actual understanding problem OP has, namely the confusion about registers.

Comment: If anything this should be a comment to correct a potential typo in the question.

Comment: I figured out the *realRegister before comming back to read the answers here. Not sure why a * must be used to write to the object referenced by the pointer in that bit but not in the baseaddress/offset version. I should have also added a tag for microcontroller or DSP to the original post.